# Is this old oval copper coin Chinese?

Tags: identification, ancient-china, numismatics

Can someone identify this old hand-stamped copper coin? Is it possibly Chinese?

> [image: Image of old, worn copper coin]

Answer (score 5):

Running a reverse image search would indicate this coin is Byzantine,not Chinese.

A similar coin can be found [on ebay](https://www.ebay.com/itm/185821053889), listed as *Coin of Byzantium Mauritius Tiberius*
[image]

Others with similar markings were sold by a dealer [here](https://bellamysworld.com/numismatic-coins-bank-notes/others-coins-bank-notes/four-byzantine-bronze-coins-weight-3830-grs) where they are listed as *Four Byzantine Bronze Coins*. This one is quite similar again:

[image]

That site also classifies the coins as [Follis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Follis)